# BigQuery - SUM values from product level and add to header level - NESTED Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to add **SUM** of the gross/net value from product line where **isVoided is false** to the header line

As an example, I have like this nested table (the main table is huge):

```
id        product.gross   product.net  product.isVoided
1         10              5            false
          20              10           true
          30              20           false
```

I would like to have:

```
id    gross  net  product.gross   product.net   product.isVoided
1     40     25   10              5             false
                  20              10            true
                  30              20            false
```

This is my beginning:

```
SELECT 
M.*, 
SUM(PR.gross) AS Gross, 
SUM(pr.net) AS Net 
FROM MAIN AS M, UNNEST(product) AS PR
GROUP BY (some how group by all???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  (SELECT AS STRUCT SUM(gross) gross, SUM(net) net FROM UNNEST(product) WHERE NOT isVoided).* 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```